# Can't read video stored in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I can store my video in my Google Cloud Bucket but I can't read it.

Here is my code :

```
url_template = (
    u'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/{bucket}/o?'
    u'uploadType=resumable'
)
upload_url = url_template.format(bucket=BUCKET_NAME)
transport = AuthorizedSession(credentials=client._credentials)
stream = io.BytesIO(stream_file.file.read())
upload = ResumableUpload(upload_url, chunk_size)
metadata = {u'name': blob.name}
upload.initiate(transport, stream, metadata, content_type)
upload.transmit_next_chunk(transport)
while upload.finished is False:
    upload.transmit_next_chunk(transport)
```

After loading the file, the file in my bucket looks like this :

[image: file with no size]

As you can see, the size of my file in the bucket is 0, it should be 24.7 MB.

So I want to know what is wrong in my code.

Comment: Code looks okay, have you tried enabling logging to see what data is being sent? Check here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging#log-level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you added the [[image]google-app-engine](/questions/tagged/google-app-engine) tag, I'll assume that you're trying to upload from GAE, although I'm not sure if it's standard or flex environment.

Regardless of standard or flex, you should use the client library provided for both environments, either [cloudstorage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/google.appengine.ext.cloudstorage) for standard, or [google-cloud-storage](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/storage/client.html) for flex.

In the GCP docs you'll find full tutorials for both [standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage) and [flex](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-cloud-storage) with detailed instructions.

Furthermore, in the [api-client-library docs](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/storage/v1) it also suggests to use the specific client library instead of the auto-generated client.